# Constant DRM entries in syslog for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: intel-graphics, drm

On a 10-year-old Dell Inspiron 1525 running Ubuntu 16.04.3 with Intel 965GM graphics and the proprietary Intel graphics drivers loaded, the syslog shows constant DRM entries like these:

```
[ 4108.682415] [drm:i965_update_wm [i915]] self-refresh entries: 80, wm: 432
[ 4170.928095] [drm:intel_set_memory_cxsr [i915]] memory self-refresh is enabled
[ 4259.864937] [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:67]
[ 4301.721636] [drm:i965_update_wm [i915]] Setting FIFO watermarks - A: 8, B: 8, C: 8, SR 432    
[ 4356.320158] [drm:intel_tv_detect [i915]] [CONNECTOR:48:SVIDEO-1] force=0
```

After bootup, the Syslog quickly shows hundreds of these kinds of entries, and displays 1,000 at a time. Yet the laptop runs OK with drivers from the Intel update tool installed six months ago. (Before that, the screen did not display properly, showing erratic lines).  Are these syslog entries normal or are they something I should try to correct, and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

From another source, I learned this behavior is an artifact of Xdiagnose, an application I used to diagnose past video issues. The large number of DRM lines went away after unchecking the graphics debug feature in Xdiagnose.